# Python not passing correct size of string to C

Tags: python, c, ctypes

When I try passing a 16 character string from python to C and scramble it, I keep getting random error codes back.

```
s = ctypes.c_wchar_p("H86ETJJJJHGFTYHr")


print(libc.hash_password(s))
```

At the start of the code I added a statement to return the size of the string back to python,
however it keeps returning a value of 8

```
if (sizeof(my_string) != 17) return sizeof(my_string);
```

If I try to return a single element of the array, it will return a number, which I am assuming is the ascii value of the character, and the code does not error out.

This works for the last element as well, which is correctly recognised as a null.

The code works within C itself perfectly. So how could I get C to accept the correct size string, or python to accept the return string?

EDIT: Forgot to mention, when I do

```
sizeof(*my_string)
```

it returns a 1

EDIT 2:
Here is the function definition

```
unsigned char *hash_password(char *input_string)
```

Comment: 17 is the length of the string. The size of a variable of type char* on 64Bit is 8 byte, and this is what sizeof returns.

Comment: I am aware the size of the string is 17, it is why I put the early return statement if it isn't 17. And okay, but I am not sure why doing sizeof(*my_string) returns a 1.

Comment: @PythonProgrammer You won't get it done wearing the Python glasses when coding in C.

Comment: @PythonProgrammer [`sizeof` operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof), [`char`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/arithmetic_types#Character_types), [`wchar_t` etc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/wide)

Comment: Has anyone worked out why C is having issues returning full strings?

Comment: I know what they mean @Wolf I didn't realise it was only taking the size of the first character for some reason.

Comment: `mystring` is a `char*`, `*mystring` refers to the *single **char*** at the pointer, `char` has size 1.  use `strlen` to count all the characters starting at the pointer up to the first null byte found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3, `"H86ETJJJJHGFTYHr"` is a `str` object made up of Unicode codepoints.  Your C function declaration is `unsigned char *hash_password(char *input_string)`.  Python `str` is marshaled as `wchar_t*` when passed via `ctypes`, not `char*`.  Use a `bytes` object for that.

Assuming `sizeof` is `ctypes.sizeof`, it works like C and returns the size of the equivalent C object.  for a `c_wchar_p`, that's a `w_char_t*`, and pointers typically have a size of 4 or 8 bytes (32- or 64-bit OS).  It is not the length of the string.

It's also *always* a good idea to declare the arguments types and return type of a function when using `ctypes`, so it can check for type and number of arguments correctly, instead of guessing:

```
import ctypes

dll = ctypes.CDLL('./your.dll')
dll.hash_password.argtypes = ctypes.c_char_p,
dll.hash_password.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
```

A quick-and-dirty example (note `printf` returns length of string printed):

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> dll = CDLL('msvcrt')
>>> dll.printf('hello\n')  # ctypes assume wchar_t* for str, so passes UTF16-encoded data
h1                         # of 68 00 65 00 ... and prints only to first null, 1 char.
>>> dll.printf.argtypes=c_char_p, # tell ctypes the correct argument type
>>> dll.printf('hello\n')           # now it detects str is incorrect.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type
>>> dll.printf(b'hello\n')          # pass bytes, and `char*` is marshaled to C
hello
6
```

Comment: Wow thanks, C isn't returning any errors now! but could you clarify what is happening exactly, as in, is C now receiving Unicode characters, or are they in ascii? When I return the string from C to python it works just fine, but when I perform arithmetic on the characters, I get things such as b'}1&t\xb6`\xf6\...'

Comment: @PythonProgrammer A byte string contains bytes.  ASCII is just convenient for display.  `h` is the ASCII character representing the byte value 0x68, but bytes are the underlying data.  `\xb6` in your example is just a display representation for the byte value 0xB6.

Answer (score 1):

In C sizeof doesn't ever return the length of the string it returns the size in memory of the variable.

For a string declared as

```
char *string;
```

Then string is a pointer to a character, and on your system it seems like pointers are 64 bits (i.e. 8 bits).

When you do `*string` in C you get the content of the first element that `string` points to - i.e. a single character.

To get the length of a string in C, use `strlen(my_string)`.

Comment: Yes, it returns the size in bytes, but I expected to see a size of 17, as each char is 1 byte right? And oh I see the problem now...Thanks, I was passing only the first char but I need **my_string to pass the whole thing right?

Comment: **mystring is only valid C if *my_string is a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof` returns the size of an object in memory. This is not the same thing as the length of a string.

In your C code, `my_string` is a *pointer* to a string. `sizeof(my_string)` is the size of this pointer: 8 bytes on a 64-bit machine. `sizeof(*my_string)` is the size of what `my_string` points to. Since you're getting 1, it likely means that there's another problem in your C code, which is that you're mixing up single-byte characters (`char`, whose size is always 1 by definition) and wide characters (`wchar_t`, whose size is almost always 2 or 4).

Your string is a null-terminated wide character string. To obtain its length in C, call [`wcslen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/wide/wcslen). Note that this means that your whole string processing code must use `wchar_t` and `wcsxxx` functions. If your string is a byte string, use `char`, `strlen` and other functions that work on byte strings.

Comment: *other functions that work on byte strings* -- you mean in Python? (I'm asking if `c_wchar_p` is always correct.)

Comment: Honestly I have no idea, I will place my function definition in an edit, so you can see what I'm passing.

Comment: @Wolf No, in C. The ctypes module will do the right thing to convert a Python string to a `char` array when you use `c_char_p` and to a `wchar` array when you use `c_wchar_p`. At least if you've set up locales and encoding correctly (which I don't know offhand how to do).

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' `c_wchar_p` vs `char*` -- that's exact the dichotomy I now see in the question ;)